# HTML-formatted email in Google App Engine (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email

How to send HTML-formatted email in Google App Engine? I just need some overview or docs, not code.

Answer (score 2):

AE uses [javamail](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail)

You can basically do:

```
String msgText = getHtmlMessageText(...);
msg.setContent(msgText, "text/html");
```

Another simple example is here [send html using javamail](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-to-send-html-mail-using-javamail) - just ignore the "sessionProperties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpServer);" in the create session part since your are using AE.  It would get ignored by AE anyway...

Or just google "javamail html".

Keep in mind you can also [send an HTML message body in addition to the plaintext message body, using multi-part messages](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail#Multi_Part_Messages)